# How To Perform a Google Search Programmatically With Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web

What tools in javascript would allow me to enter text programmatically into google and click the search button?

EDIT:

Basically, I need to identify a text box, fill it in, then press the "Search" button all within my code.  It doesn't have to be google, that's just an example.

Comment: just plain dom manipulation if you are on google page

Comment: I want to be able to specify the google url and then do things like "document.getelementbyid" to allow me to type text from my code and press the button from my code

Comment: You can run your code in dev console

Comment: Is there no way to specify a url and interact with it in the same way you would GET data from a url?

Comment: I suggest you give it your best shot - write some code, and when you get stuck come back here and ask and paste in your code up to that point. SO works best when questions have code for us to look at and correct. Even if you can't write much of the code, write as much as you can.

Comment: @nietsnegttiw no, you can read google, but not take the user to it and start running your own code. That would lead to a bunch of security issues. You would need either a server side language or making a chome/firefox extension for more permission

Comment: So there's no tool in JS that would programmatically click a button on a website via some javascript application?

Comment: @nietsnegttiw from your own website? no. You can always only modify the website you are on

Answer (score 0):

If you need to google search the content from an input form you can open a new window at the target with -

window.open("https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q="+inputFormValue);

Replace all of the spaces with +'s(regex, lookup or ask if needed). Also remove or escape any double quotes.

If this doesn't suit your problem you'll need to explain the requirements a bit more.

Comment: Basically, I need to identify a text box, fill it in, then press the "Search" button all within my code.  It doesn't have to be google, that's just an example.

Comment: As in you open up inspect element and submit a code block as you personally browse the page? Or more automation style( programmatically open up a browser, find elements, manipulate elements etc), then you need to use selenium or something like it. A little heavier duty but still readily doable. - If you want the full automation the javascript you're talking about won't cut it, you need server-side javascript or other scripting language.